# HANA XS Engine: get Data with Umlaut Ü Ä Ö ( german letters)

Tags: javascript, rest, hana, xsengine

I create some RestAPI with XSJS to send data to other Apps.

I am facing an issue with german letters like Ü Ä and Ö.

Here a sample example:

I create a POST RestApi.

This is my object header :

```
{
    "In": "Hallo ÄÄÖ" 
}
```

and here the code is XSJS File (Same with XSJS Template):

> function handlePost() { var bodyStr = $.request.body ?
>   $.request.body.asString() : undefined; if ( bodyStr === undefined ){ 
>   $.response.status = $.net.http.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;  return
>   {"myResult":"Missing BODY"}; } var output = bodyStr.In;.....

Here what I got from HANA XS

```
{
  "INPUT": "Hallo Ã\u0096Ã\u0084Ã\u009c"
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the

> contenttype

and

> charset

of the response according to your requirement

**$.response.contentType**

Example :

> $.response.contentType = "application/json";